Pronunciation of "Gen Z"
Good evening,
My mother tongue is German and I learned at school that the letter Z is pronounced like "Zedd". However, I've noticed that in German TV documentaries, the "Z" in "Gen Z" is usually pronounced like "See", i.e. "Gen C" - which strictly speaking means something else.
I would therefore be very interested to know how people with English as their mother tongue pronounce "Gen Z" and if "Zedd" why not "See".

The letter Z is famously pronounced Zed in British English and Zee  (not See) in American English.

See https://english.stackexchange.com/q/6470/425655. But German pronunciation of the sound made by "z" is different than English, so in English it's not the same as "see." The sibilance of "z" in English is voiced—that is, practice making an "sss" hiss but humming at the same time.

@AndyBonner They have /z/ in German. They even have a word that's pronounced /zi:/, sie.

American letter Z is pronounced identical to "Sie" in "Haben Sie eine Frage?"

In British English the name of the letter "Z" is "zed". In American English the name of the letter is "zee" (but never "see").
Sometimes there is crossover from one dialect to another, for example when a British speaker is speaking in an American context, but generally in the UK people will say "Gen Zed" and in the USA "Gen Zee"  (I think Australians and New Zealanders say "Zed" and Canadians say "Zee")
In Germany the dialect taught at school is usually British, but you will be exposed to a lot of American culture through movies, music, children's television, documentaries and so on.
You should also be aware that the /z/ sound in English is unlike the sound indicated by the same letter in German.  Both American and British sound "z" as a voiced dental fricative [z].
